# Windows Preinstallation Environment (winpe) Web Browser

Tags: portable, portable-apps, winpe

I'm trying to add any internet browser to WinPE but have failed to find a way as of yet. I've tried tons of portable apps like chrome portable, firefox portable, QtWeb portable, and more with the solution provided here: [Adding programs to WinPE](https://superuser.com/questions/431250/adding-programs-to-winpe) but with no successful results. I always get the error message with the title `This app can't run on your PC` and the message `to find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher`. Do I need to install any extra packages or something?

I'm definitely running a 64 BIT WinPE copy. Version 10.0.17134.1

Comment: Is the application 32-bit or 64-bit?  It makes a huge difference within WinPE since there is no concept of Windows on Windows 64 (WoW64)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding programs to WinPE](https://superuser.com/questions/431250/adding-programs-to-winpe)

Comment: @Moab did you read the question? I addressed that.

Comment: @MarkDodsons then add your new information to your original; question. We cannot answer without all the relevant information such as what specific version of WinPE you are using. Marking as duplicate means just that, its a duplicate question the way it is currently being asked regardless of your research. It does look like you are on the right path to an answer though.